# Неправильное отображение в Opera

Tags: кроссбраузерность

Опера старых версий крашит страницу

http://denezhko.ru/index.php/photo/svadebnajafotografija

Из-за чего такое происходит и как лучше все исправить?

Comment: Скриншоты!

Comment: http://rghost.ru/35646795/image.png - в 5

Answer (score 1):

Ну ты нашел чего ради "парится" она же мертвая уже, а вообще тут надо верстку изучать и специфику оперы 5, я бы например установил разницу между версткой тех страниц, которые нормально отображаются и тех, что ненормально, от этого бы и плясал ...